# Degree necessary of a polynomial?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, real-analysis, polynomials, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-theory

Given $-1<a<b<0$, I want to find a polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$ such that $f(x)\in[a,b]$ at every $x\in[b^2,a^2]$ and $f(0)=0$. What is minimum degree that is needed and maximum degree that will suffice?

What is degree as function of $a,b$ that is necessary and sufficient using chebyshev polynomials?

Is $O(1)$ degree sufficient?

Quadratic will not work. Min of quadratic goes below $[a,b]$ at some point in middle of $[b^2,a^2]$. Example take $b=−1/9,a=−1/3$. Quadratic is $3x(−13+81x)/4$ which takes min value at $x=13/162\in[1/81,1/9]$ with value $-169/432<-1/3$. Although $-((111 x)/10) + (729 x^2)/4 - (19683 x^3)/20$ seems to work. Is answer cubic always?

I think theory of Tchebyshev polynomials or Jackson's theorem in approximation theory should be useful here.

The question is about finding a polynomial that hits zero one place, and then is squeezed in a rectangle in some other region with rectangle $\mathsf{Height} = |a-b|$ here while $\mathsf{Width}=|a^2-b^2|=|(a-b)(a+b)|\leq |a-b|=\mathsf{Height}$ if $a+b\leq1$, $\mathsf{Width}=|a^2-b^2|=|(a-b)(a+b)|\geq |a-b|=\mathsf{Height}$ if $a+b\geq1$.

Comment: The answer to the first paragraph is 2: it's easy to see that 1 isn't sufficient, but on the other hand the unique quadratic going through the origin, $(b^2, b)$, and $(a^2, a)$ has the desired property. I don't think this is appropriate for MO.

Comment: Yes, draw the picture.

Comment: Oops, you're right.

Comment: I think this is actually a reasonable question. The question is about finding a polynomial that hits zero one place, and then is squeezed in a rectangle in some other region. Intuitively, I would expect the required degree to go up as the rectangle gets longer.

Comment: Yes, I meant "longer relative to height". But the Gerhard's partial answer is more complete.

Comment: I agree but degree of Tchebyshev poly needed is not clear.

Comment: Although bounds have been given, I think it is still worth noting a simple argument that no constant degree suffices. You can rescale the problem to say that you restrict the polynomial to take values between $-1$ and $1$ on the interval $[-1,1]$, and ask for the polynomial to take the value $y_0$ at the point $x_0$. The set of polynomials of a fixed degree satisfying the condition on the interval is compact, so for any $x_0$, the set of values taken by the polynomials is compact, hence not all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @DouglasZare How does this help here? $x_0,y_0$ is origin which is fixed here.

Comment: Doug is rescaling and shifting so that the $x$ window changes from $[b^2,a^2]$ to $[-1,1]$ and the $y$ window changes from $[a,b]$ to $[-1,1]$. After the rescaling $x_0$ and $y_0$ will both be varying.

Comment: It will be nice to think of a full topological solution if possible. That will be nice and turn heads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: The solution has been edited in order to answer a more general question.

We can always rescale to obtain the following problem: find a polynomial $f(x)$ of minimal degree such that $f(0)=0$ and $f([\beta,1])\subseteq [\alpha,1]$. Here $1>\alpha=\sqrt\beta=b/a>0$ in the original problem.

Suppose we have a polynomial $f_0(x)$ satisfying $f([\beta,1])\subseteq [\alpha,1]$, but $f_0(0)\leq 0$. Then it is possible to construct a solution to the original problem of degree $\deg f_0$ by the formula 
$$f(x)=\beta(f_0(x)),\quad \beta(y)=\frac{y-1}{1-f_0(0)}+1,$$
since $\beta([\alpha,1])\subseteq[\alpha,1]$.

Therefore the following is true

> Lemma: The problem can be solved with a polynomial of degree $n$ if and only if $\inf_{f\in P_n} f(0)\leq 0$, where $P_n$ is the space of polynomials $f$ of degree $n$ having the property $f([\beta,1])\subseteq [\alpha,1]$.

Now, this $\inf$ is known and given by Chebyshev polynomials. Indeed, let $Q_n$ denote the space of polynomials $g$ of degree $n$ satisfying $g([-1,1])\in [-1,1]$. Then we have
$$
g\in Q_n\Longrightarrow 1-(1-\alpha)\frac{g\left(1-2\frac{x-\beta}{1-\beta}\right)+1}{2}\in P_n
$$
and this correspondence is bijective. Therefore, the $\inf$ in question is given by
$$
\inf_{f\in P_n} f(0)=1-(1-\alpha)\frac{1+\sup_{g\in Q_n} g\left(\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}\right)}{2},
$$
and since $\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}>1$, we have
$$
\sup_{g\in Q_n} g\left(\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}\right)=T_n\left(\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}\right).
$$

Therefore we get the following statement

> The problem can be solved in degree $n$ if and only if $T_n\left(\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}\right)\geq\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}$, where $0<\alpha,\beta<1$, and in the original problem $\alpha=\sqrt\beta=b/a$

Alternatively, defining $\gamma=\frac{1+\sqrt\beta}{1-\sqrt\beta}=\frac{a+b}{a-b}$, $\delta=\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}$ we get the inequality
$$
\cosh (n\log\gamma)\geq\delta.
$$
Looking for the threshold value, replace this by equality and obtain
$$
n=\left\lceil \frac{\cosh^{-1}\delta}{\log\gamma}\right\rceil=\left\lceil \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\frac{b}{a}+O(b^2/a^2)\right)\right\rceil,
$$
where the last equality sign is for the original problem.
Keeping just the leading term gives a pretty good approximation.

Comment: @Turbo, yes, it is just one of their extremal properties. I should have probably stated this more explicitly.

Comment: @Turbo I believe the same strategy applies. You just have to shift and rescale the Chebyshev polynomial to the new box and check if the result is non-positive at 0.

Comment: @Turbo, Oh sorry I misread your first question. The statement follows because since we computed the $\inf$ using this $\sup$, we can just plug it into the lemma.

Comment: @Turbo, my final formula does not apply to your new problem. You will have to modify the solution a little. If you understand this one, then it should be no problem. The answer should be like $\alpha(T_n(\beta(0)))\geq 0$, where $\alpha$ maps $[-1,1]$ linearly onto $[a,b]$ and $\beta$ maps $[c,d]$ linearly onto $[-1,1]$.

Comment: How did you get "The problem can be solved in degree $n$ if and only if $T_n\left(\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)\geq\frac{1+\sqrt\alpha}{1-\sqrt\alpha}$, $\alpha=b^2/a^2$"? I mean why does $\geq \frac{1+\sqrt\alpha}{1-\sqrt\alpha}$ hold?

Comment: could you give more details to your steps?

Comment: @Turbo I updated the solution so that it answers the more general question. Also, I fixed a typo which might have confused you, sorry for that. I hope the new version is typo-free.

Comment: It is still not clear why you infer $T_n(1+\beta/1-\beta)\geq\delta$.

Comment: @Turbo it follows from the lemma and calculation of the $\inf$ by simple algebra, unless I made other typos.

Comment: could you fill the missing steps?

Comment: oh i see $2/(1-\alpha)-1=(1+\alpha)/(1-\alpha)$.

Comment: @Turbo The formula for Chebyshev polynomial follows from $T_n(x)=\frac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}{2}$

Comment: wiki says $\log \gamma$ should be $cosh^{-1}\gamma$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Explicit_expressions

Answer (score 4):

**Version 2**

Here is some experimental evidence.  Like most people here I'm using $-f(x)$ and assuming $0<b<a<1$.
Consider $b=1/100$ and $a=i/100$.

For $2\le i\le 3$, there is a quadratic polynomial.
For $4\le i\le 8$, the least degree is 3.
For $9\le i\le 15$, the least degree is 4.
For $16\le i\le 24$, the least degree is 5.
For $24\le i\le 35$, the least degree is 6.  - corrected as per Peter K
For $36\le i\le 48$, the least degree is 7.
For $49\le i\le 63$, the least degree is 8.
For $64\le i\le 80$, the least degree is 9.
For $81\le i\le 99$, the least degree is 10.

Turbo noticed that these cutoffs are close to squares.

Next consider $a=1-\frac1n$, $b=\frac1n$.  We find:

For $3\le n\le 4$, there is a quadratic poynomial.
For $5\le n\le 9$, the least degree is 3.
For $10\le n\le 16$, the least degree is 4.
For $17\le n\le 25$, the least degree is 5.
For $26\le n\le 36$, the least degree is 6.
For $37\le n\le 49$, the least degree is 7.
For $50\le n\le 64$, the least degree is 8.
For $65\le n\le 81$, the least degree is 9.
For $82\le n\le 100$, the least degree is 10.
For $101\le n\le 121$, the least degree is 11.
For $122\le n\le 144$, the least degree is 12.

**Turbo's square-root conjecture is looking pretty good, and I see PeterKravchuk has proved it.** The solutions look very much like scaled-and-shifted Chebyshev polynomials inside the box and surely that is the place to look for an analytic upper bound on the degree.

**Here is my method.** We are looking for $c_1,\ldots,c_d$ such that $f(x)=c_1x+\cdots +c_dx^d$ has the desired properties.  Let $X$ be some finite subset of $[b^2,a^2]$ including the two endpoints. Initially I take $X$ to consist of $2d+1$ points uniformly spaced.

Make a linear program whose variables are $m,c_1,\ldots,c_d$ and whose constraints are $f(x)\in[b+m,a-m]$ for $x\in X$ and $m\ge 0$.  Maximize $m$. If the constraints are infeasible, we have proved that no good polynomial of degree at most $d$ exists. If there is a solution, let $f(x)$ be that polynomial. Check if $f(x)$ is good by finding its turning points and evaluating $f(x)$ there. (Alternatively, use Sturm sequences to prove this in rational arithmetic.) If $f(x)$ is good, we are done; if not, add (an accurate rational approximation of) the turning points of $f(x)$ to $X$ and repeat.

This method won't work if there are only solutions which hit the bounds exactly, but I didn't find any other case when it doesn't work.  Usually only 2 or 3 iterations are needed.

Maple worksheets: [version 16](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/ConstrainedPolynomial.mw), [older version (not tested)](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/ConstrainedPolynomial.mws).

Comment: Just curious. How did you convert this to linear programming problem?

Comment: Are you guessing truth is close to $\mathsf{degree}\approx 1+\sqrt{\frac{a}b}$ if $a+b<1$?

Comment: @Turbo: I'll add this in a few hours.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, I might be disagreeing with you in some borderline cases. E.g. I think $i=35$ should be possible with $n=6$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay, I think that's the only disagreement.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk, that's what my program gives too, I apparently mistyped.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Your approach seems like some kind of dual version to Peter's approach no?

Comment: @Turbo, my approach can find particular solutions and will generalise to more complex requirements. However Peter's theoretical approach is much better for the problem you asked, especially since it is constructive.

Comment: @Turbo:  I added links.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement that $f(0)=0$ and that $f(x)$ is a polynomial allows us to rewrite the problem:
What polynomial $g(x)$ is there so that $f(x)=xg(x)$ meets the desired restrictions?  We can now ignore $x=0$ and ask what polynomial fits between the two hyperbolas $y= b^2/x$ and $y=a^2/x$ in the interval $[a,b] \subset [-1,0]$?

I first picture the target endpoints which are vertical lines with ordinates between $b^2/a$ and $a$ at abcissa $a$, and the other with ordinates between $b$ and $a^2/b$ at abcissa $b$ .  (In case I have the terms wrong, draw your own picture.)  What makes the problem interesting is that the coordinates depend only on two parameters $b$ and $a$; for four parameters $c$ and $d$ replacing $a^2$ and $b^2$, it should be easy to generate examples which require polynomials of arbitrarily high degree.

I have not put pencil to paper on this, but my mental picture tells me that for both $a$ and $b$ greater than -1/2, or both less than -1/2, a linear function $g(x)$ will thread both needles simultaneously, and that it gets more challenging when $a$ and $b$ are further apart on both sides of 1/2.  Even then, I imagine a low degree polynomial is needed for these cases.

I suspect $g(x)$ of the form $K\cdot$Cheybshev$/x$ will yield to a similar analysis.

Gerhard "Coffee First; Opinion Change Later" Paseman, 2015.05.05

Comment: I see the example with both a and b greater than -1/2.  I guess that will be the problematic section.  Gerhard "Time To Get A Pencil" Paseman, 2015.05.05

Comment: What is degree of Tchebyshev Polynomial that is needed?